# htaccess Rewriterule for Multilanguage Website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Multilanguage-Website with 2 domains like www.domain.com and www.domain.de

Now I want to define some RewriteRules like:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I dont know how I can change it to work for both domains at once. Changing that target just without the domain doesnt work.

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^category-[0-9]{1,4}/(.*) http://www.domain.de/category/$1 [R=301, L]
```

This would redirect the user to the .de-domain. Doesnt matter which domain he was on preview pages. So visitors from domain.com would be suddenly on domain.de on some specific pages with this rule.

I want this rule to work for both domains and dont know how to write the target path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

RewriteBase /
and RewriteRule without domain